# Возможно ли отсортировать булевое значение используя ORDER BY

Tags: база-данных, order-by

У меня есть таблица где я фильтрую списки используя ORDER BY ('asc' и 'desc'). Так же в таблице есть булевые значения(избранное) и вот они у меня не фильтруются. Есть ли в ORDER BY способ для фильтрации булевых значений?

Comment: Как **order by** относится к react? Приведите примеры данных и как вы пытались отсортировать. И еще момент... order сортировка, а вы про фильтрацию пишите

Answer (score 2, accepted):

да это можно делать, попробуйте это следующим образом:

```
    ORDER BY
      CASE WHEN boolean_column = true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC,
       -- Другие колонки, по которым вы хотите сортировать
```

тут есть маленький момент - значения с true в колонке boolean_column будут выше в списке, чем значения со значением false. Это делается с помощью выражения CASE, которое возвращает 1 для значений true и 0 для значений false, и сортировки этой колонки по убыванию.

надеюсь не много помог)

Answer (score 1):

Смотря что за СУБД. В postgress вполне работает:

```
order by f1 desc
```

Или так:

```
order by (f1 is true) desc
```

Отсортирует как true, false, null